# What is the best way to calculate proportions in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Suppose I have some kind of discreet variable, let's say a string and I want to know the proportion of occurrences of each value of the string. Is there a recommended way to do this in Snowflake ?

Answer (score 11):

Snowflake supports **[RATIO_TO_REPORT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/ratio_to_report.html)**:

> *Returns the ratio of a value within a group to the sum of the values within the group*

```
SELECT C_SALUTATION,
       RATIO_TO_REPORT(COUNT(*)) OVER() AS ratio
FROM "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCDS_SF100TCL".CUSTOMER
GROUP BY C_SALUTATION;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is any way to do this that is **recommended for Snowflake in particular**, but the standard way to do this from my experience is by using a window function. For example:

```sql
select C_SALUTATION as title, COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER()
from "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCDS_SF100TCL"
group by C_SALUTATION;
```

```sql
TITLE   PROPORTION
Ms.     11.676401
Mr.     16.591405
Miss    11.680596
Sir     16.586719
NULL     3.501119
Mrs.    11.682914
Dr.     28.280846
```